# How do I remove the Angular Material mat-form-field initial background color and background color on hover and focus?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I am trying to change my Angular Material's mat-form-field's background color to white by writing styles in my global `styles.scss`.

This is what I have now.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="name-input">
  <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
  <input matInput id="name" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter your first name and last name...">
</mat-form-field>
```

styles.scss:

```
.mdc-text-field, .mdc-text-field--filled, 
.mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper, .mdc-text-field--invalid, .mdc-text-field--focused,
.ng-tns-c1205077789-1,
.ng-tns-c1205077789-2,
.ng-tns-c1205077789-3 {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

As you can see, I have these complex class names like `ng-tns-c1205077789-3`. I found those in inspector, these classes assign to div inside each mat-form-field on focus and they are unique. Without those, my input's background color does not change to white when hovering or on focus. What I want is to find a more generic class that can change background color of all my input fields in both focused and hover states. I can't be looking for every unique style for every mat-form-field.

Every alternative on how to customize component styles is appreciated!

Comment: Those class names like `.ng-tns-c1205077789-3` are generated at runtime and you cannot rely on them to always be the same.  That is a part of the view encapsulation in Angular so that you can have a component with it's own CSS rules that will not interfere with other components.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I understand, so that's why I am looking for the best alternative. I think I am using the wrong or not specific enough classes...

Comment: One option is to disable encapsulation in a component with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` so your CSS is no longer encapsulated, but you have to be careful with this as any styles you set on that component might "leak" to others now.  Have you looked at the docs for Angular Material styling? https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the following CSS in `styles.scss`:

```
// Manipulate initial background color
.mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
  background-color: white !important;
}

// Manipulate background color on hover and focus
.mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

With the solution above, you can manipulate all `<mat-form-field>`s in your project at once, no matter what the `<mat-form-field>` is wrapping (e.g., the input, textarea, select, etc.).

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xfsxxh-kv1bhv?file=src%2Fstyles.scss).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for. I needed to add !important to mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay's background color to make it work, but it certainly does the trick. By the way, do you happen to know any good article on these classes for component manipulation? I guess there is no detailed documentation about it even now, in 2023.

Comment: @he1dj You're welcome. :) I don't know of any sources for such questions. I figured this out on my own.